# Calculate Earth-based planetary positions given a date, time, and timezone

Tags: python, object-oriented

I have a project where the user supplies a date, time, and timezone, and my code will calculate a bunch of coordinates on the Earth. There are four sets of coordinates setA, setB, setC, setD. Coordinates setA and setB make up a great circle around the Earth. Likewise for coordinates setC and setD. The user is interested in plotting these coordinates in a 2D mapping system like Google Maps.

### CoordinatesCalculator.py

```
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np

from . import utils
from . import config
from . import astronomy

class CoordinatesCalculator:
   def __init__(self) -> None:
      self.results = None

   def calculate(self, timestamp: dt.datetime, longitude: float, latitude: float) -> dict[str, dict[str, np.array]]:
      self.results = {}

      for name, data in config.CELESTIAL_INTERESTS.items():
         # Calculate coordinates
         a, b = sets_A_and_B()
         c = setC()
         d = setD()

         self.results[name] = {
            "setA": a,
            "setB": b,
            "setC": c,
            "setD": d
         }

      return self.results
   
   def set_C(self, target: utils.CelestialTarget, time: dt.datetime) -> float:
      return astronomy.subpoint_meridian(target, time)
   
   def set_D(self, c: float) -> float:
      return (c % 360) - 180 # degrees
   
   def sets_A_and_B(self, target: utils.CelestialTarget, time: dt.datetime):      
      return astronomy.terminator_great_circle(target, time, samples = config.SAMPLES)

   def print_sets_C_and_D(self) -> None:
      ...
         
   def export_csv(self, targets: list[str], latitude_first = False) -> None:
      ...
   
   def plot2D(self, targets: list[str]) -> None:
      ...
```

### How this is used by the user

```
import datetime as dt

import pytz

from .CoordinatesCalculator import CoordinatesCalculator

if __name__ == "__main__":
   timestamp_string = "2021-06-20 06:00:00"
   tz = "Europe/London"
   latitude = -113
   longitude = 46

   # Build an aware datetime object
   naive_observer_time = dt.datetime.strptime(timestamp_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   aware_observer_time = pytz.timezone(tz).localize(naive_observer_time)
   
   # Calculate the results
   calculator = CoordinatesCalculator()
   results = calculator.calculate(aware_observer_time, longitude, latitude)

   # Print, plot, and export the results
   calculator.print_sets_C_and_D()
   calculator.plot2D(["Sun", "Moon", "Mars"])
   calculator.export_csv(["Sun", "Moon", "Mars"])
```

### Return dictionary

```
results = {
   "Sun": {
      "setA": np.array([]),
      "setB": np.array([]),
      "setC": np.array([]),
      "setD": np.array([])
   },
   "Moon": {
      "setA": np.array([]),
      "setB": np.array([]),
      "setC": np.array([]),
      "setD": np.array([])
   },
   "Mars": {
      "setA": np.array([]),
      "setB": np.array([]),
      "setC": np.array([]),
      "setD": np.array([])
   }
}
```

### My Questions

1. The `CoordinatesCalculator` class doesn't really have a state, should this just become a function?
2. Should my return dictionary also have parameters that the user inputted? I kind of want some object that contains everything about the calculation (e.g. the time, date, time zone, and the resulting coordinates). The issue with the following is it makes it weird to iterate over if the user wants to just iterate over the coordinates data.

   ```
   results = {
      "Date": "2021-06-20",
      "Time": "06:00:00",
      "Timezone": "Europe/London",
      "Sun": {
         "setA": np.array([]),
         "setB": np.array([]),
         "setC": np.array([]),
         "setD": np.array([])
      },
      "Moon": {
         "setA": np.array([]),
         "setB": np.array([]),
         "setC": np.array([]),
         "setD": np.array([])
      }
   }
   ```
3. The `CoordinatesCalculator` is handling functions that belong to the results, such as `export_csv` and `plot2D`. Should I make the results its own class `Results` that then has the `export_csv` and `plot2D`? This would satisfy the itch for an object that contains everything about the calculation. Something like:

   ```
   class Results:
      def __init__(self, date, time, timezone, setA, setB, setC, setD):
         self.date = date
         self.time = time
         self.timezone = timezone
         self.setA = setA
         self.setB = setB
         self.setC = setC
         self.setD = setD

      def print_sets_C_and_D(self):
         pass

      def export_csv(self):
         pass

      def plot2D(self):
         pass

      def to_json(self):
         pass
   ```
4. If I wanted to turn this into an API, does it suffice to just have a `Results.to_json()` function? Maybe the JSON results would have the structure, so that the user can iterate over the results in a clean way:

   ```
   {
      "date": date,
      "time": time,
      "timezone": timezone,
      "results": {
         "Sun": {
            "setA": [],
            "setB": [],
            "setC": [],
            "setD": []
         },
         "Moon": {
            "setA": [],
            "setB": [],
            "setC": [],
            "setD": []
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Instead of requiring the user to supply the timepoint in three different parameters, perhaps accept a single UTC timepoint, and suggest ways to convert from other things (local time or separate day/time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Should `CoordinatesCalculator` just become a function?

Yes.
It wants to be a module offering some functions
that will calculate, plot, export to CSV and so on.

Use an `_` underscore prefix for any private helper functions
that a user would have no need of calling directly.
That way we offer a relatively simple Public API
for each new user to learn about.

> 2. Should my return dictionary also have parameters that the user inputted?

Yes.

> The issue ... is it makes it weird to iterate over if the user wants to just iterate over the coordinates data.

I respectfully disagree.
We see this all the time in e.g. RESTful JSON APIs.

```
for name, coords in result['Sun']:
    assert name.startswith('set')
    ...
```

Or to examine more coordinates:

```
celestial_bodies = ["Sun", "Moon", "Mars"]
for body in celestial_bodies:
    for name, coords in result[body]:
        assert name.startswith("set")
        ...
```

Alternatively, define a helper function that dynamically discovers
the relevant set of celestial bodies by probing the result,
and iterate over names returned by the helper.

You could also define variant API endpoints,
variant function names, accept a set of desired
celestial bodies, and so on.
But that sounds like putting the wrong amount
of complexity in the API, given that the
items are small to transport across TCP
and are not time consuming to produce.
We're probably better off to just let
the client pick out its favorite values.
It can readily define a helper that
extracts its favorite subset,
and then a different client can
similarly define a helper for *its*
slightly different needs.
Such an approach will tend to reduce version churn
in the server's API, as the third or fourth client
explores additional regions of the
[powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)
of celestial bodies.

An aspect of the API which
*is* very weird is to see date + time broken up.
Offer it as a single
[ISO-8601](https://xkcd.com/1179)
timestamp.

Also, consider normalizing the user's input to UTC,
so your timestamps all end with `"Z"`.
Do hang onto the original timezone name as a separate field.

I imagine that your `astronomy` module
uses TAI (or [TT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Time)) on the inside, rather than UTC.
Consider including both in the result dict,
or at least include the number of seconds they differ by
for the given timestamp.

> 3. Should I make the results its own class Result that then has the export_csv and plot2D?

Yes, a `Result` class would be lovely.

Consider making it a
[dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

> 4. If I wanted to turn this into a [web] API, does it suffice to just have a Results.to_json() function?

Yup, pretty much.

You may find
[.asdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)
convenient.

Or use a
[@dataclass_json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json)
decorator.

It is a fact of life that Things Change.
This includes software, and the APIs defined by software.
It is possible that your webclient caller is already
aware of which version of your API they're accessing,
for example because the URI started
"https://api.example.com/v2/calculate".
Alternatively you might wish to insert a
[SemVer](https://semver.org)
`k: v` pair like `"version": "2.0.1"`
so the client will know what keys to expect,
and what semantics are imposed on the values.
It is customary to bump the version after
implementing a bugfix or offering new features.

You solicit a (lat, long) coordinate.
Sometimes users supply 53 bits of
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats)
significand, with most of the low order bits
being meaningless.
Consider deliberately
[rounding](https://xkcd.com/2170)
to ~ 6 decimal places, as one-meter resolution
on Earth's surface likely suffices for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry what I meant about the dictionary being weird to iterate over is when several bodies are included. For example, see the "Return Dictionary" section, where there are multiple bodies. It's easy to iterate over that like `body, coordinates in results.items()`, but if there were to be a "timestamp", and "timezone" key in the `results` dictionary, then `body, coordinates in results.items()` wouldn't work. But perhaps my amendment is still nil to your suggestion that this is common practice in RESTful APIs

Comment: Ok, I get your concern. I will flesh out my remark a bit more to address it. I had based it just on the example `result` record, which only included a single celestial body, the Sun.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I've updated the examples to include two bodies. My proposed solution would be to stuff all they `body, coordinates` key, value pairs into a `data` section inside the `results` dictionary (see the example JSON object in question 4).

Comment: Well, it's your API, so you can define the rules however you want. Personally, I tend to find a key which is literally labeled `data` to be on the annoying side, as it is hopelessly vague and it just pushes the bits I care about One More Level deeper down in the nesting. OTOH if we have keys named `data_for_weekly_report` and `data_for_monthly_report`, _then_ the level of nesting is actually pulling its weight, organizing the data and making it self descriptive. Your experiences in writing client code will inform your server-side design decisions. Make things easy for the client.

Comment: This is my first time trying to design an API for something that will be stuck in the future, so sorry if this question appears to be too in the weeds of this stuff. What might be a nice way to design the `Results` class. What i'm thinking is `CalculatorResults(iso8601: string, collection: list[Coordinates])` is the response from the calculator, and a `Coordinates` class looks like: `Coordinates(body_name: str, setA: list, setB: list, setC: float, setD: float)`. The idea of "set" here is incorrect for C and D, they're only for this example. `for coordinates in response.collection` could work

Comment: I suppose it begs the question, is it better for the user to query a dictionary `response.coordinates["Sun"].setA` or `for coordinates in response.results: if (coordinates.Name == "Sun") return coordinates.setA`. Actually, I like the former

Comment: Definitely the former. But again, write one or two client calls, then pay attention to anything that was slightly verbose or annoying. Here, you might want the `result` object to offer a convenience function for grabbing solar coordinates, if the client is likely to usually examine that part of the answer. // Don't call it `iso8601`; prefer a name of `timestamp`. It gets serialized as `str` but will probably be deserialized to a `datetime.datetime` UTC timezone-aware object for client convenience. // Recommend you post a separate Question for your (singular!) `Result` class.